# create scapy packet protocol with reuse of payload for more than one fields

Tags: python, networking, scapy, pcap, packets

I'm trying to create my own protocol for scapy and have been stuck for the last couple of days.

What I'm looking to do is use the first 14 bytes for the first layer, 6 for dst mac, 6 src mac, 2 for padding. The rest of the packet would be the payload.

The problem is I'm not exactly sure how to make the 5th and 6th byte in the packet to be a field that would give an ShortField value.

```
class MyEther(Packet):

   name = "MyEther"

   fields_desc =[
          MACField("dst", None),
          MACField("src", None),
          StrLenField('padding', None, length_from=lambda x: 2)
   ]
```

help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi ! What do you mean by "the 5th and 6th byte" ? In your layer, the 5 and 6 bytes are in the dst MACField :/

Comment: Exactly, I'm looking to read the 5 and 6 byte also as a short. These two bytes is representative as a port in my protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the use of MACField is not appropriate. You should use an IntField followed by a ShortField, for each MACField.

```
fields_desc = [
    IntField(“a”, 0),
    ShortField(“b”, 0), # here are your 5-6 bytes
    ....
]
```

If you really know what you are doing, however, and you know you need MACField, you can use

```
struct.unpack(“!H”, mac2str(packet.dst)[4:6])
```

(mac2str is imported from scapy)

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing just yet, scapy's documentation is good but it is not thorough enough set this up. How would you set the 5th and 6th bytes as a field in the packet without shifting the bytes? I do need the MAC field to be there as it is a field necessary for our protocol